# Why does R tell me the two factor levels are "0" "1" But then lists 1s and 2s and plots them as 1 and 2?

Tags: r

I do nothing fancy, just turn my data of 0s and 1s into factors with as.factor() and factor(), which do the same thing.

```
data$Class <- as.factor(as.numeric(data$Class))
str(data$Class)
data$Class

Output:
Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
   [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This seems contradictory.
My naive assumption is it is a bug.

I tried making a new variable

```
data$Class2 <- ifelse(data$Class == '1', 1, 0)
data$Class2 <- factor(data$Class2)
data$Class2
```

Then I also tried forcing it by doing it with

```
factor(data$Class, levels = c("0","1"), labels = c("0","1"))
```

These all produce the same outcome.

[image: Plotting the Class against other variable]

Comment: Can you share how you are trying to plot the data? As well as the data itself. What you are seeing is expected. You created a factor that contains 1s and 0s. 0s are the first level and 1s are the second level.

Comment: ```{r}
for (param in columns ) {
  dm.logit = glm(Class ~ ., family=binomial(link="logit"), data=data[ , c("Class", param)])
  plot(data[,param], data$Class, col="blue4", ylab = 'Class', xlab = param)
  abline(h=c(0,1),col="light blue")
}
```      Note the issues start before the plotting happens. See what happens when I type str(data$Class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're (understandably) confused by the differences between the underlying representation of the object and the way it is printed.

```r
x <- factor(c(0,0,1,1,1))
```

Underneath, this is stored as a set of integer codes starting from 1 and a set of *levels* corresponding to each code: 1 = "0", 2 = "1" in this case.

`str(x)` tells you about the **str**ucture
of the object:

```r
str(x)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2
```

This is printing out the class of the object (a "factor with two levels, '0' and '1'") and its *underlying integer values* (1,1,2,2,2).

Using `print` prints the *level* corresponding to each element, *without quotation marks*, and a list of the elements:

```r
print(x)
[1] 0 0 1 1 1
Levels: 0 1
```

Using `print(., quote = TRUE)` might be less confusing:

```r
print(x, quote=TRUE)
[1] "0" "0" "1" "1" "1"
Levels: "0" "1"
```

While `glm` is happy to take a factor as a response variable, you have to do more work to plot them, e.g.

```r
mm <- transform(mtcars, am = factor(am))  ## 0-1 levels
ff <- glm(am ~ mpg, family = binomial, data = mm)
## plot: suppress axes so we can add our own labels
plot(as.numeric(am) ~ mpg, data = mm, axes = FALSE, ylab = "am")
axis(side = 1)
## add class labels to y-axis
axis(side = 2, at = 1:2, labels = levels(mm$am))
pframe <- data.frame(mpg = seq(min(mm$mpg), max(mm$mpg), length = 51))
## find predicted probability *and add 1 to line up with axis*
pframe$am <- 1 + predict(ff, newdata = pframe, type = "response")
with(pframe, lines(mpg, am))
```

Comment: I am then running a glm model with the Class as the target variable, and it seems to work. But then I plot with   ```plot(data[,param], data$Class, col="blue4", ylab = 'Class', xlab = param)``` And this plots the Class as 1 and 2.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking it shouldn't plot the Class based on its underlying levels?